# Out of Range Error while accessing date from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, t-sql

I want to fetch the maximum value of date from the table. But I always get an 'OutofRangeException' error. I changed my query several times.

- `Due_Date` column has `date` data type
- `Due_Date_Sample` is a string var
- `Due_Date_var` is a `DateTime` var

My code:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(Main.connectionString))
{
    string commandString = "SELECT TOP 1 FORMAT(Due_Date,'dd-MM-yyyy') FROM Transactions WHERE Plot_Code='" + Plot_Code_var + "' ORDER BY Due_Date DESC;";

    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, sqlCon);

    sqlCon.Open();

    SqlDataReader dr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        date_control_var = 2;
        Due_Date_Sample = (dr["Due_Date"].ToString());
        Due_Date_var = DateTime.Parse(Due_Date_Sample.ToString());
    }

    dr.Close();
}
```

Comment: What 's line of code it throw the exception?

Comment: Check to see if it is null.  The database excepts a null for DateTime but c# doesn't.

Comment: Due_Date_Sample = dr["Due_Date"].ToString();

Comment: I am checking for null in another try catch....
This piece of code runs when the value is not null

Comment: Please, also consider using parameters instead of string concatenation in your SQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to give an alias to the selected value, e.g.: `FORMAT(Due_Date,'dd-MM-yyyy') as Due_Date`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(Main.connectionString))
                    {
                        string commandString = "SELECT TOP 1 FORMAT(Due_Date,'dd-MM-yyyy') as Due_Date FROM Transactions where Plot_Code='" + Plot_Code_var + "' ORDER BY Due_Date DESC;";

                        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, sqlCon);
                        sqlCon.Open();
                        SqlDataReader dr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            date_control_var = 2;
                            Due_Date_Sample = (dr["Due_Date"].ToString());
                            Due_Date_var = DateTime.Parse(Due_Date_Sample.ToString());

                        }
                        dr.Close();
                    }
```